# is socket() always followed by bind()?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

mostly, I have copied the standard template calls for tcp and udp.  I always see one socket() call followed by one bind() call.  under what circumstances would this not be the case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind a TCP socket if you're about to connect it to a listening port.

You don't need to bind a UDP socket if you don't care what port number it uses and what interface it works via. UDP will auto-bind it the first time you send something.